# Magento 2: Can't call parent function in JS / knockout file

Tags: magento2, javascript, knockoutjs

I'm having trouble receiving the return value from a function in the parent file.

As you can see in `Magento_Tax/js/view/checkout/summary/shipping.js`, it's calling functions in the (grand)parent file (`Magento_Checkout/js/view/summary/abstract-total.js` - getFormattedPrice() ) but I'm receiving a JS error when I try to call `this.getValue()` in the parent file (this.getValue() is not a function).

Can anyone spot why I can't call `this.getValue()`?

Magento_Checkout/js/view/summary/shipping.js 
(Parent file – I haven't touched this file apart from adding in the string return value for demo purposes).

```
define(
[
'ko',
'jquery',
'Magento_Checkout/js/view/summary/abstract-total',
'Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote'
],
function (ko, $, Component, quote) {
    return Component.extend({
        defaults: {
            template: 'Magento_Checkout/summary/shipping'
        },
        quoteIsVirtual: quote.isVirtual(),
        totals: quote.getTotals(),

        getShippingMethodTitle: function() {
            if (!this.isCalculated()) {
                return '';
            }
            var shippingMethod = quote.shippingMethod();
            return shippingMethod ? shippingMethod.carrier_title + " - " + shippingMethod.method_title : '';
        },

        isCalculated: function() {
            return this.totals() && this.isFullMode() && null != quote.shippingMethod();
        },

        getValue: function() {

            return 'this is the value I want to see in the #Magento_Tax/checkout/summary/shipping.html';

        }

    });
  }
);
```

Magento_Tax/js/view/checkout/summary/shipping.js
( I added just the newVar: ko.observable(this.getValue()) )

```
define(
[   
'ko',
'jquery',
'Magento_Checkout/js/view/summary/shipping',
'Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote',
'Magento_Checkout/js/model/step-navigator'
],
function (ko, $, Component, quote, stepNavigator ) {
    var displayMode = window.checkoutConfig.reviewShippingDisplayMode;

    return Component.extend({
        defaults: {
            displayMode: displayMode,
            template: 'Magento_Tax/checkout/summary/shipping'
        },


        newVar: ko.observable(this.getValue()),


        isBothPricesDisplayed: function() {
            return 'both' == this.displayMode
        },
        isIncludingDisplayed: function() {
            return 'including' == this.displayMode;
        },
        isExcludingDisplayed: function() {
            return 'excluding' == this.displayMode;
        },
        isCalculated: function() {
            return this.totals() && this.isFullMode() && null != quote.shippingMethod();
        },
        getIncludingValue: function() {
            if (!this.isCalculated()) {
                return this.notCalculatedMessage;
            }
            var price =  this.totals().shipping_incl_tax;
            return this.getFormattedPrice(price);
        },
        getExcludingValue: function() {
            if (!this.isCalculated()) {
                return this.notCalculatedMessage;
            }
            var price =  this.totals().shipping_amount;
            return this.getFormattedPrice(price);
        }
    });
}
);
```

Magento_Tax/checkout/summary/shipping

```
// This is what I want to update with the return value from getValue()

<span data-bind="text: newVar() "></span>

...
```

Answer (score 4):

From my understanding, to set the observable the way Magento uses knockout you would have to create an `initialize` function starting with `this._super();` which will allow to call the parents.

```
define(
[   
'ko',
'jquery',
'Magento_Checkout/js/view/summary/shipping',
'Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote',
'Magento_Checkout/js/model/step-navigator'
],
function (ko, $, Component, quote, stepNavigator ) {
    var displayMode = window.checkoutConfig.reviewShippingDisplayMode;

    return Component.extend({
        defaults: {
            displayMode: displayMode,
            template: 'Magento_Tax/checkout/summary/shipping'
        },

        initialize: function () {
            this._super();

            this.newVar = ko.observable(this.getValue());
        },


        ...


    });
}
);
```

You should then be able to call the parents from anywhere in the code after the initialize function.

**Also `data-bind` should be:**

```
<span data-bind="text: newVar"></span>
```

**Useful tips for using `this`:**

If the need comes to access `this` from inside computed observables or keeping track of it using function overriding the `this` variable, you may simply use the appoach below.

```
self = this;
self.firstName = ko.observable('Some');
self.lastName = ko.observable('One');
self.fullName = ko.computed(function() {
    return self.firstName() + " " + self.lastName();
});
```

To pass `this` or any variable inside of a computed observable:

```
this.fullName = ko.computed(function() {
    return this.firstName() + " " + this.lastName();
}, this); //PASSED VARIABLE
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I agreed with most of what you've said but, the `Magento_Tax/js/view/checkout/summary/shipping.js` doesn't have an initialize function with `this._super();` and yet, it's able to call its parent functions. For example, `this.getFormattedPrice(price);`

Comment: Indeed I had noticed it while I wrote my answer and unfortunately I don't understand it enough yet to tell why `this.getFormattedPrice(price);` is working without the initialize function. Have you tried to call `this.getValue()` directly outside of the ko.observable() function? You may try `initialize: function () { alert(this.getValue()); },` without `this._super()` to see if it is giving the output or undefined. If it works then it may mean that the problem reside with using `ko.observable()` outside of the initialize function only.